# why object type variable needs to be declare as transient?

Tags: spring

```
Component
public class CustomerConfiguration implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 7193597488669071066L;

  @Id
  private String id;
  private  Object  customerInformation;
}
```

For Above code SONARLINT giving suggestion you should declare customerInformation  as a transient variable .but in case of  ID  variable
   it's fine.

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: transient means that it won't be serialized nor persisted. So, if it needs to be made transient, it means that the person who designed that class decided that this field shouldn't be serialized nor persisted. Ask that person why, because we have no idea of what this field is used for.

Comment: My personal opinion is that using serialization is a bad idea in general, that using JPA entities to serialize data from one system to another is an even worse idea, and that having non-persistent fields in an entity, whose main point is precisely to represent persistent state, is, most of the time, a sign of bad design (violation of the single responsibility principle)